# Velocity template variable name with a special character - a dot

Tags: java, javascript, velocity

I need to access a value of a Velocity template's variable named:

```
$myFeature.enabled
```

Mind the *dot* within the name. It is defined in the code as:

```
myFeature.enabled=true
```

The problem is that, when I want to get the value of that variable withing **html** context with the following expression:

```
'${myFeature.enabled}'
```

it is not resolved and just gives:

```
"${myFeature.enabled}"
```

I tried to escape the dot with **\** or change apostrophes to **"** but without luck.

Changing the name of the variable to a one without a dot is not an easy option for various reasons, so please suggest **any other solutions**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is as simple as:

Velocity [variable naming](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/vtl-reference-guide.html): **does not allow dots within variable**

Also [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp10.5/escaping-characters-in-velocity-variables-and-directives.html):

> To use a $SINGLE.VARIABLE.IDENTIFIER.WITH.DOTS no backslash is
>   required. **The engine will not treat such expression as a variable** to
>   be processed because a Velocity **variable cannot contain dots** according
>   to the Velocity variable notation.

Links:

- http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/vtl-reference-guide.html
- http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp10.5/escaping-characters-in-velocity-variables-and-directives.html

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Velocity variable notation](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/vtl-reference-guide.html), a variable cannot contain dots.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do to work-around the issue, is to add the velocity context itself to the context:

```
VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
context.put("globals", context); // <-- TADA
context.put("myFeature.enabled", Boolean.TRUE);
// ...
```

then from the template, do:

```
#if ($globals.get('myFeature.enabled'))
...
#end
```

Comment: This is a great workaround. It's so good it almost warrants asking Velocity to always bind some special key name to the context itself, but there isn't any magic name that could be invented that might not conflict with any other existing code.